# MongoDB - $text search does not work in pipeline and returns error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am trying to search `$lookup` value with `$text` operator. But it returns the following error when executed -

> MongoServerError: Unrecognized expression '$text'

Here is the code -

```
model.findSearchedItemsByConditions = async (conditions = {}, text) => {
  try {
    return await ItemModel.aggregate([
        {
            $match: conditions
        },
        {
            $lookup:
            {
                from: 'datas',
                let: { 'itemId': '$_id' },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr:
                            {
                                $and: [
                                    { $eq: ["$parentId", "$$itemId"] },
                                    { $text: { $search: text } }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "data"
            }
        },
        {
            $sort: {
                createdAt: -1
            }
        }
    ]);
} catch (error) {
    console.log({ error });
}
}
```

The query works fine when I remove the `$text` operator.

Note: `Index` is enabled via Mongoose Schema.

Comment: What MongoDB Server version are you using?

Comment: Here is the MongoDB version - 4.1.1

Comment: It may be a _"bug"_ that was present in that version of the server.  A previous [bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38716) noted a similar problem.  It was fixed but I don't know which version the fix first appeared.

Comment: The latest version is now 6 but my used one is 4, do you have any idea whether the latest version will fix the issue?

Comment: I did a quick [mongoplayground.net test](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HEUAPpzANPf) and was surprised there was an error message.  IDK for sure, but for now you may need to _"invert"_ your query by starting with the `datas` collection or perhaps `"$regex"` filter `"data"` returned by `"$lookup"`.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38716  and don't use $expr in the $match. $text is a search operator, not an expression.